# A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AbstractNode?'

Tags: html, flutter

I am using [Html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html/versions) library to show html taq but i got in error says: **A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AbstractNode?'.**

My Dart version is 3.1.1 and fully compatable with Html library.

**Code**

```
 Html(
                                    data: """<div>
                                              <h1>Demo Page</h1>
                                              <p>This is a fantastic product that you should buy!</p>
                                              <h3>Features</h3>
                                              <ul>
                                                <li>It actually works</li>
                                                <li>It exists</li>
                                                <li>It doesn't cost much!</li>
                                              </ul>
                                              <!--You can pretty much put any html in here!-->
                                            </div>""",
                                      style: {
                                        '#': Style(
                                          fontSize: FontSize(18),
                                          maxLines: 10,
                                          textOverflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        ),
                                      },
                                    ),
```

**Screenshot of the errors**
[image]

Comment: What version of the `flutter_html` package are you using?

Comment: The latest version flutter_html 2.2.1,  but I tried the old versions too but still got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be fixed with the new beta version of flutter_html

```
flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.2
```